# Missing number error in todonotes with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, todonotes

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\todo{\today}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \
l.5 \todo{\today}
```

The same code works if you don't use the `siunitx` package, if you use `\today` outside `\todo`, or if you write `today` instead of `\today`.

Why? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem occurs because `\today` is not "robust" (in the LaTeX sense of the word). If you change

```
\todo{\today}
```

to

```
\todo{\protect\today}
```

you can use both packages just fine. Alternatively, load the `etoolbox` package and issue the instruction `\robustify{\today}` in the preamble.